# Shorthand key path in switch statement?

Tags: swift, swift-keypath

I have a method that takes a key path for a type, however it is giving me a compile error when I try to use the shorthand version of the key path.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
struct MyType {
    let prop1: String
    let prop2: Int
    let prop3: Bool
}

func test(_ keyPath: PartialKeyPath<MyType>) {
    switch keyPath {
    case \MyType.prop1:
        print("prop1")
    case \MyType.prop2:
        print("prop1")
    case \MyType.prop3:
        print("prop1")
    default:
        break
    }
}

test(\MyType.prop1)
```

In the `switch` statement, is it possible to do `case \.prop1` instead of specifying the root? When I try this I get this error:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

It is also forcing me to specify a `default` case even though I've specified all the properties of the type. Is there a reason for this as well? Thanks for any help.

Comment: With respect to the required default case: Note that (as an example) `\MyType.prop1.startIndex` and `\MyType.prop3.hashValue` would also be possible arguments for your function.

Comment: It looks related to this bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5578